# I need to connect with Remote Database from Xamarin application

Tags: c#, android, ios, database, xamarin

Visual studio version : 2019.
Database: MySql

For android, ios & UWP.

I am having my remote database in godaddy windows Hosting .
my Button click event code is as follows

```html
private void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 string connectionString;
 string server = "my_db_ip";
 string database = "my_DB_Name";
 string uid = "user";
 string password = "123456";
     connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
     database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
 try
 {
 MySqlConnection ms = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
         ms.Open();
 DisplayAlert("Message", "Connection open", "OK");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 DisplayAlert("Message", ex.Message, "OK");
 }
```

```html
private void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 string connectionString;
 string server = "my_db_ip";
 string database = "my_DB_Name";
 string uid = "user";
 string password = "123456";
     connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
     database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
 try
 {
 MySqlConnection ms = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
         ms.Open();
 DisplayAlert("Message", "Connection open", "OK");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 DisplayAlert("Message", ex.Message, "OK");
 }
```

and i got this error :- mysql.data.mysqlclient.replication.replicationmanager’ threw an exception
If you can attach any example for this will be helful for me i have searched many link but not working for me.
Somone post any solution regarding this above sccenario.
Thank You,

Comment: Please search before posting.  There are MANY similar questions about there regarding this error.  Second, connecting directly to a DB from a mobile client is a HORRIBLE idea, please do not do this.

Comment: thats y am asking for idea am new to this what should i do for this.

Comment: You need to tell us what you’ve tried, otherwise we will just suggest the same fixes.  Consider using a web service instead of connecting directly to the db